# How to use appspotmail address to send in App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, email

According to the link [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail#Senders_and_Recipients), I can use an email address of the form `xxx@APP-ID.appspotmail.com` but how do I create an email address like that so I can use it? I can send emails with my own email `user1@gmail.com` but I want the send from to be `admin@myapp.appspotmail.com` so I tried inputting that when setting the `setFrom` but no email comes through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In appengine whenever you need to send email, you can send it only via administrator or owner of the GAE Application. Although you can add multiple owners to your app from the **Application Permissions Setting Tab** to send emails from multiple emails.

The **admin@XXX.appspot.com** can be used to receive the emails in GAE.

**Note :** Remember email will not work when sending email from **localhost** it will work only when the app is deployed to appengine and the email is sent from the email that has owner privilege for the app.

You can find the email under the application setting of your GAE console shown in image below.

[image: GAE Console]

Comment: The link says the sender address can be one of the following types: `Any valid email receiving address for the app (such as xxx@APP-ID.appspotmail.com).` so `admin@XXX.appspot.com` can only be used to receive, not send?

Comment: @Jack this is my personal experience in all my apps even I tried to send the email using **xxx@xxx.appspot.com** but things were not working hence I suggested you the right way to send emails.

Comment: @Jack you can find the email **xxx@APPID.appspot.com** in application settings of your GAE App Dashboard.

Comment: Actually nm, it was working.  I was sending it to another email address that was supposed to forward to my main email.  It wasn't forwarding because the was an issue with the subject line being empty and therefore didn't match the filter.  Are you sure you are using `@xxx.appspotmail.com` and not `@xxx.appspot.com`?

Comment: @Jack please check my updated answer, the email format would be like that as depicted in the image

Comment: I don't think that's an email address.  It's for connecting to Google Services.  The format `admin@myappid.appspotmail.com` works for me, I was having issues with the forwarding in my gmail accounts (unrelated to app engine).

Answer (score 2):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23101387/1058612) by [Ankur Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1120792/ankur-jain) is still correct, but the Cloud/GAE Console has changed since then, so there's a different screen for adding email addresses.

To get there:

1. Go to your console for your app (try this [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine)).
2. Go to **Settings**
3. Under **Settings**, choose the **Email senders** tab. You should be able to add an email address there.

Some things that were not immediately obvious to me (despite reading the [email docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/#who_can_send_mail)):

1. While you can "Add" your personal email address (for testing, for example), it has to be a Gmail account.
2. You **can't add** `[anything]@[APP_NAME].appspotmail.com` or `[anything]@[APP_ALIAS].appspotmail.com` because they are already authorized internally.

So, in the case of #2, using `noreply@{my-app-name}.appspotmail.com` worked when I deployed the app and sent mail from that account.

Comment: This worked, and it matches the (current) docs @JohnnyCoder linked.  However, it betrays an expectation that Akur Jain's should also work (APPID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) since that's what _other_ Google docs imply (ie their bottom example here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/sending-mail-with-mail-api).  _Should_ the APPID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com account work to send email from anymore?

Comment: wow they really should mention that those emails are already authorized internally. Thanks!